# Changing Solr from single core to multicore, want to keep index data

Tags: solr

I currently have a single solr index with a large volume of data. I am converting this into a multicore instance, and one of the cores will be the existing index.

The data directory is already even in the right location, so theoretically nothing should need to be moved or changed.

I know adding new cores in is not a problem, but I was wondering if moving from not specifying cores to explicitly having them will in some way invalidate the current index?

Answer (score 2):

Multicore setup will not affect your existing core. You just need to configure solr.xml in your solr home to point to different cores and ensure that the old core has all the data/config as per the definition.

As long as solr schema remains same your old data dir should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your existing index will get corrupted. Just to be safe though, try it on a smaller test index on another machine before doing it on the machine with the big index. The [Solr CoreAdmin wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) could also be of help to you.